# Count words in a string

Tags: c++

I need som help with counting words in a string s.
count the number of words in a string s.
Words are separated by whitespace.
Has a sol

```
istringstream iss(s);
string temp;
int words = 0;
while (iss >> temp) {
++words;
}
```

But if we change the question to 
count the number of words in a string s.
Words are separated by ;.             or if we have ; or : as separator .

Is it possible do change the delimiter from whitespace to  ; in this solution?

```
istringstream iss(s);
int words = distance(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
istream_iterator<string>());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is also possible to use regular expressions:

```
   std::regex rx("(\\w+)(;|,)*");
   std::string text = "this;is,a;test";

   auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), rx);
   auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

   auto count = std::distance(words_begin, words_end);

   std::cout << "count: " << count << std::endl;

   for(auto i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i)
   {
      auto match = *i;
      std::cout << match[1] << '\n';
   }
```

The output is:

```
count: 4
this
is
a
test
```

Comment: regex is a nice and flexible way. +1

Comment: Can u explain rx("(\\w+)(;|,)*");? 
why do we have \\w+ and *

Comment: You should read about regular expression syntax. `\w` is any word character. `+` means 1 or more occurrences, `*` means any number of occurrences (including zero). `()` define a capturing group.

Answer (score 3):

You can use getline with character delimiter.

```
istream& std::getline (istream& is, string& str, char delim);
```

Something like:

```
std::replace_if(s.begin(), s.end(), isColon, ';');
istringstream iss(s);
string temp;
int words = 0;
while (std::getline(iss,temp,';') {
  ++words;
}
```

And the predicate:

```
bool isColon (char c) { return (c == ';'); }
```

Comment: is is possible to do a ; or :. Make them both a delimiter

Comment: @user2975699 In that case you can first replace all occurances of ';' with ':' so that you get a single delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

Some simple hand crafted loops:

```
#include <cctype>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    unsigned result = 0;
    std::string s = "Hello world";
    std::string::const_iterator c = s.begin();
    while(c != s.end() && std::isspace(*c)) ++c;
    while(c != s.end() && ! std::isspace(*c)) {
        ++result;
        while(++c != s.end() &&  ! std::isspace(*c));
        if(c != s.end()) {
            while(std::isspace(*c)) ++c;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "Words in '" << s << "': " << result << '\n';
}
```