# Counting two words in a string

Tags: python-2.7

I have to count two words 'cat' and 'dog' from a string.

If the counts are equal, I would like to return `True` else `false`.

For example, for input `"dogdoginincatcat"` my method should return `True`.

Here is my code,

```
def cat_dog(str):
   count=0
   count1=0
   for i in range(len(str)):
      if str[i:i+3] == 'cat':
         count=count+1
      if str[i:i+3] == 'dog':
         count1=count+1
   if count == count1:
      return True
   else:
      return False
cat_dog('catdog')
```

Answer (score 1):

just one line to do this using `count` on a string:

```
z= "dogdoginincatcat"

print(z.count("cat")==z.count("dog"))
```

Comment: Thank you so much..May i know the attempt in other language such as c++..

Comment: that's a very different question. And already has an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406583/count-words-in-a-string

Comment: Thank you for the link..One more question.. Another question. I would need to Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except i will accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.

count_code('aaacodebbb') → 1
count_code('codexxcode') → 2
count_code('cozexxcope') → 2

May i have the attempt..Thanks in Advance again..

Answer (score 0):

First, DON'T use str (the string class) as a variable name. While Python won't cry at that very moment, you'll regret it later.

Second, it doesn't look like the count and count1 are indented as inside blocks of the 'if' statements, so your code is seen as:

```
for i in range(len(str))
    if something:
        pass
    count = count + 1
    if something_else:
        pass
    count1 = count1 + 1
```

Other than that, your code seems to work