# How to search a txt file for regex?

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to output the number of email addresses in a text file in HTML format using regex, I can open the file and read the file but I'm not sure how to use regex to search the file for the regex pattern.

update: ok I used a test text file and it works but not on the actual text file that is in HTML format, it outputs the phone numbers but not the number of email addresses.

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ifstream htmlText;
string line;


string eduEmail = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\.edu$";
string nonEduEmail = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.+-]+\.com$";
string phoneNumbers = "[[:digit:]]{2}-[[:digit:]]{3}-[[:digit:]]{4}";

int eduEmails = 0;
int nonEduEmails = 0;
int num_phoneNumbers = 0;

htmlText.open("ltudirectory.txt");


if (htmlText.good())
{
    while (getline(htmlText, line))
    {
        cout << line << endl;
        regex r_edu(eduEmail); //the pattern to search for edu emails
        regex r_com(nonEduEmail); //the pattern to search for .com emails
        regex r_phoneNumbers(phoneNumbers); //the pattern to search for .com    emails


        bool eduEmail_match = regex_search(line, r_edu);
        bool nonEmail_match = regex_search(line, r_com);
        bool phoneNumber_match = regex_search(line, r_phoneNumbers);


        if (eduEmail_match)
        {
            ++eduEmails;
        }
        if (nonEmail_match)
        {
            ++nonEduEmails;
        }
        if (phoneNumber_match)
        {
            ++num_phoneNumbers;
        }
    }
}


htmlText.close();
cout << "Emails ending with .edu : " << eduEmails << endl;
cout << "Emails ending with .com : " << nonEduEmails << endl;
cout << "Number of Phone Numbers: " << num_phoneNumbers << endl;


system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Here is a link that shows one example:   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681670/extract-email-sub-strings-from-large-document

Comment: is there a C++ example?

Comment: THis should do the trick: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22406583/count-words-in-a-string/22406894#22406894

Comment: ok i think i have it walter thanks

Comment: You can just add an if statement to check if match is true or false then increment a variable based on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
ifstream htmlText;
string line;
string eduEmail = "(\\w+)(\\.|_)?(\\w*)@(\\w+)(\\.(\\w+))+";


int testNum = 0;

list<string> l;


htmlText.open("ltudirectory.txt");
if (htmlText.good())
{
    while (getline(htmlText, line))
    {
        regex e(eduEmail); // the pattern
        bool match = regex_search(line, e);
        if (match) {
          ++testNum;
       }
    }
}

htmlText.close();

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: is there a faster way search because the text file is kinda long

Comment: You could read the file into memory, then perform your search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925051/fast-textfile-reading-in-c